# How to load the whole app when using 3D touch to access specific View

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller, 3dtouch

I have a 3D touch quick action that accesses a specific viewcontroller in my app.

```
 let mainStoryboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let initialViewController : UIViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "newCardVC") as! ViewController
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

The problem I'm facing is that although the specified viewcontroller does appear, and other viewcontrollers that are "children" (meaning you segue from this vc to them) are also appearing and working, the "parent" viewcontroller is not loaded. Therefore my dismiss viewcontroller and other methods are not working. How do I load all the viewcontrollers in my app, although I'm 3D quick action accessing my 3rd vc in vc hierarchy ?

Thanks .

Comment: Have you tried loading the first view controller and navigating manually to the one needed?

Comment: By manually do you mean I load a vc then press buttons to navigate by hand or manually/programatically navigate to desired vc ?

Comment: Well, by manually I meant "programmatically" of course - calling `performSegue` and/or `pushViewController:` or other methods you use to move between content. If this would require to call button handlers to trigger necessary changes, this may also work.

Comment: I haven't tried that but I have noticed other developers (ie instagram) do it like that. Now that you've also suggested it, I will try it like that. Thanks for the help.